# How to uninstall VMware Player?

Tags: vmware-player, software-uninstall

I want to uninstall VMware Player on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system. How should I uninstall it?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

This issue has been discussed previously over here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1364485

Comment: That still left a bunch of files. Can I just delete vmware directories?

Comment: How to do it using GUI?

Comment: This worked for me: 

sudo bash VMware-Player-12.1.1-3770994.x86_64.bundle -u vmware-player

Comment: Thanks! for me it was `sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation` and the player was a part of it.

Comment: It asks if you want to keep configuration information, just type No.

Answer (score 35):

```
sudo vmware-installer -l
sudo vmware-installer -u PRODUCT-NAME
```

With the first command, you can see what products you have. With the second, you can choose which product to uninstall. For instance, to uninstall VMware Player, please enter this in a terminal window:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer, especially to make sure the reader can uninstall everything they intend to.

Answer (score 31):

```
sudo  vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

Used to uninstall complete vmware-workstation package including vmware-player.

Comment: Does not work if only player is installed

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the command line Lorenzo Lerate provided to make it work for me for version 12.5.6:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

Comment: I think Lorenzo meant that his readers should substitute `PRODUCT-NAME` with the actual product name, e. g. `vmware-player`.

Answer (score 3):

The [official documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.get_started.doc%2FGUID-05E4C876-F32C-49D2-82B4-8C759691E7F5.html) states you have to run this:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

Answer (score 2):

**Uninstalling VMware in linux machine**

Use command with root permission to uninstall

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

if you removed some files before using above command
the command will not work properly

For this issue:
Reinstall VMware workstation again

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-Full-16.2.4-20089737.x86_64.bundle
```

and use this command again :)

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also confused in uninstalling but these commands work for me:

1. sudo vmware-installer -l(it gives the product name)
2. sudo vmware-installer -u product name(in my case it was 'vmware-player')

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

According to [official documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-05E4C876-F32C-49D2-82B4-8C759691E7F5.html) which mentions "Uninstall Workstation Pro from a Linux Host"

You might also have to want to uninstall a package named `open-vm-tool` separately.