# How to uninstall VMware Workstation 10.0.3 from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, software-uninstall, vmware-workstation

I want to uninstall VMware Workstation 10.0.3 from my Ubuntu 14.04. I used the '.bundle' file to install VMware Workstation.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and run this command to uninstall VMware Workstation:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

<sub>**Reference:** [VMware Workstation 10 Documentation Center: Uninstall Workstation from a Linux Host](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.get_started.doc/GUID-05E4C876-F32C-49D2-82B4-8C759691E7F5.html?resultof=%2522%2575%256e%2569%256e%2573%2574%2561%256c%256c%2522%2520%2522%2575%256e%2569%256e%2573%2574%2561%256c%2522%2520)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can try manual uninstall:

Prepend all commands with sudo, or switch to root using this command:

```
sudo su
```

Shut down all VMware applications and services.

```
/etc/init.d/vmware stop
```

Verify that all processes have stopped:

```
lsmod | grep vm
```

Note: A zero must be listed beside VMware related modules to indicate that they are no longer running.

Move the VMware libraries to the /tmp directory:

```
cd /lib/modules/kernel_version/misc
mv vm* /tmp
```

Note: If the kernel has ever been updated, you must check and move the files from multiple paths. Substitute the kernel version where indicated above.

Unload the kernel modules:

```
rmmod vmnet.o
rmmod vmmon.o
rmmod vmci.o
rmmod vmblock.o
rmmod vmppuser.o
```

Remove the VMware startup scripts:

```
rm /etc/rc2.d/*vmware*
rm /etc/rc3.d/*vmware*
rm /etc/rc5.d/*vmware*
rm /etc/rc6.d/*vmware*
```

Remove the remaining VMware files and directories:

```
rm -rf /etc/vmware*
rm /usr/bin/vmware-usbarbitrator
rm /usr/bin/vmnet*
rm -r /usr/lib/vmware*
rm -r /usr/share/doc/vmware*
```

Source: [Manually uninstalling VMware Workstation from Linux hosts (38)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=38)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `vmware-installer`; already posted in here ->[How to uninstall VMware Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151099/how-to-uninstall-vmware-player-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Comment: I used to '  .bundle ' file to install vmworkstion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed .bundle packages, use below command to open again that installer. then the installer opens and checking if you have already installed this packages then installer list for you "unistall" or "remove" option to uninstall the package.

if your installation file located in home directory this command would be:

```
sudo ./yourbundleFileName.bundle
```